# Is Enterprise Search Center an Enterprise Feature?

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, features, edition, enterprise

I need to implement an enterprise search center for a customer, but the customer doesn't have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition.

Is the Enterprise Search Center available within all SharePoint 2013 Editions or only in the Enterprise Version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the site template Enterprise Search Center is available in the SharePoint Server 2013 standard edition.

The features of search **NOT** available in standard version is:

- Content Search Web Part
- Custom entity extraction
- Extensible content processing
- Query rules—advanced actions
- Search vertical: “Video”
- Tunable Relevancy

Reference: [SharePoint 2013 feature comparison chart all editions](https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/)